# Expo: what is the difference between expo build and expo upload

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

What are difference between expo build and upload. Does upload `cmd` still return a standalone app. I realized if i run on Expo Client will work fine but when build a standalone version, the application does not behave the same again.

Answer (score 2):

The commands `build` and `upload` are very different ones. The `build` command ([Expo documentation on building](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v33.0.0/distribution/building-standalone-apps/)) builds a standalone app, while the 'upload' command ([Expo documentation on uploading](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v33.0.0/distribution/uploading-apps/)) uploads the standalone app that you've built to the App Store or the Play Store (Your Choice).